# Reference to a chunk in Rmarkdown (v2)

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown

After a while using knitr with latex I'm trying Rmarkdown, principallly because the possibility of having multiple outputs make easier the sharing with colleagues.

My problem is how to reference to chunk for figures in Rmd?

in Rnw classically you make `\ref{fig:chunk_name}`

Is reference to chunk directly supported, in Rmarkdown, or just internal links to sections etc. are supported?
In a positive case, how refer to a chunk like the following?

````
```{r my_chunk}
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt, mpg)
```
````

Thank you for your help!!

*Edit*
This is the header, I need something more?

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "bbrill"
date: "2015/01/15"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        fig_caption : true
---
```

Comment: If the chunk is named (my_chunk), then it should work as normal: \ref{fig:my_chunk}

Comment: I will check again...

Comment: It doesn't, I just have ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok the problem was in the knitr formatting options, because it lacks of `fig.cap =""`, which is needed by Latex to build a figure environnement.

Because of my first try with Rmarkdown I thought the problem was that hyperref was not supported (it was evidently not supported in markdown v1), or to other things related to my newbie use of markdown...

I'm sorry, I was crazy for nothing.

The problem was in the lack of fig.cap in the options so, this works:

````
```{r my_chunk, fig.cap = ""}
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt, mpg)
```
````

see fig `\ref{my_chunk}`

Answer (score 1):

(this answer only applies to using Rmarkdown to create html pages,  Sorry I didn't relize you were making PDFs until the HEADER was included in the original question.)

You can set an anchor using HTML:

````
<a id="my_chunk"></a>
```{r }
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt, mpg)  
```
````

and refer to it using a markdown link:

```
See [this code chunk](#my_chunk) for details
```

make sure there isn't a blank line between the the anchor and the previous text, or you will have extra wide blank space between code chunk and the text which precedes the code chunk.

Comment: For what it's worth, the chunk names are not retained in the HTML, and I suspect the same is true for PDF documents.